# Problems with hyperbolic functions - Integration

Tags: calculus

Now I want to evaluate the integral $\int \sqrt{x^2-4} \,dx$

The method using trig substitution, $x=2 \sec(\theta)$, I get the following answer:
$$\frac 12 x \sqrt{x^2-4}-2 \ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-4}|+C$$

Now, I'm using a faster method that is basically integration by inspection:

$$\int\sqrt{x^2-4} \,dx=\int \frac{x^2-4}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}dx$$
$$=\int \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}-\frac{4}{\sqrt{x^2-4}}dx=\int x \,d(\sqrt{x^2-4)}-4 \cosh^{-1}(x)$$

I'm sure many of you notice the issue here! $\cosh^{-1}(x)=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-4})$, NOT $\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2-4}|$. My answer exists for $x>2$, whereas my answer from the trig substitution exists for all $x>2$ and $x<-2$. How can I fix that? My answer here is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hyperbolic cosine substitution is a problem. Really we are making the substitution $t=\cosh^{-1}(x/2)$, where by $\cosh^{-1}(u)$ one means the number $\ge 0$ whose hyperbolic cosine is $u$.  That assumes implicitly that $x\ge 2$.  For $x\le -2$, the correct substitution is $t=\cosh^{-1}(-x/2)$, or equivalently $x=-2\cosh t$.

**Remark:** The function $\cosh t$ is *even*, so does not have an inverse, unless we restrict the domain. In this, $\cosh t$ behaves very much like $t^2$.

Comment: Dont you get $-2+2\sqrt{2}$ and this is positive.

Comment: Yup, that's the part I'm stuck. Perhaps for x < or equal to 2, we have:
$$=\int x \,d(\sqrt{x^2-4)}-4 \cosh^{-1}(-x/2)$$

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now...
When x < -2, we have 
$=\int x \,d(\sqrt{x^2-4)}+4 \cosh^{-1}(-x/2) +C$
Correct?!

Comment: You are welcome.  It is now time to delete the comments.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, if I were to use a hyperbolic substitution, I would have to do it in two cases, right? $x = 2 \cosh(\theta)$ when $x>2$ and $x = -2 \cosh(\theta)$ when $x<-2$, right? If so, wouldn't it be easier if I used the sign function, or do you have other ideas?

Comment: Two comments: (i) I would myself avoid the signum function, it substitutes "algebra" for concrete contact with the geometry. (ii) Often, when we have solved a problem for positive $x$, a glance at the answer is enough to tell us how to adjust the answer for negative $x$.

Comment: That's true. Together with both the positive and negative answer, we can amalgamate them into an absolute value answer, right? That's one extra step for those who want to use a $\cosh u$ substitution because it's not one-to-one.

Comment: Right. If we feel like it we can get a single expression. In real world applications, the issue tends not to come up. The function we are integrating has a "void" in the interval $(-2,2)$. In applications, we are firmly living in the right half of the world (usually) or the left half.